Required() : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
I'm trying to implement the js.Build feature from the Hugo framework, but I'm encountering an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined." I have also attached a screenshot.

Does anyone have any ideas about this issue?
I need solution for this problem

require isn't a javascript "standard" function ... why do you think it should be defined? I'm assuming the error is not being reported by Go, but by some javascript engine

require is a function that's missing on your end. In order to solve this problem, you will need to load RequireJS, if you are working on the client-side, then create a <script> tag, like
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sample Project</title>
        <!-- data-main attribute tells require.js to load
             scripts/main.js after require.js loads. -->
        <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Sample Project</h1>
    </body>
</html>


See https://requirejs.org/docs/start.html
If you need requirejs on your server-side, then, depending on what server you are using, load it according to its dialect.

My understanding is this tool is meant to be run "server-side", it's a build process, if that's correct... then suggesting the user needs requirejs is kinda silly? Are we just guessing?

@KevinB the require function is being called unsuccessfully, so RequireJS is missing. Therefore, the solution is to have require JS and that's the solution independently of whether it's needed on server-side or client-side. I have given an example how it can be added to client-side and explained that on server-side one would need to add itt accordingly to what server is in use. Using npm, for example it would be npm install requirejs.

It's also entirely possible that they have server-side code within client side code that simply needs to be moved where it belongs. If they were simply trying to use require on the front end for the purpose it existed and actually needed require.js, it's a duplicate and should instead be closed.
